# Can we set data from a plist to Keychain in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychain

Can we set data from a plist to Keychain in iOS? If we can do what is the correct approach. Also please let me know if there is any regular tutorial on the same.

Comment: Key store? Do you mean the KeyChain? Can you given an exmaple of what you have tried?

Comment: yes.. i mean key chain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to save the data in `keychain`? probably because it is safe. Then you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` to save the encoded the plist data.

to store the **encoded** data in plist:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:dataPath];
```

For your questions to get the data from plist file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.plist"];
ObjectClassName *fetchedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dataPath];
```

to store the data in keychain:

```
[UICKeyChainStore setString:userPassword forKey:keychainKeyUserPassword];
```

Comment: Yea.. I have to save it in key chain.. i will be getting some settings related data in a plist file and i have to set it in key chain.. can you help me here.

Comment: Get the data from plist file code will do the job. you should change the name of the file with yours -> filename.plist

Comment: Thanks Mihriban.. I have read the contents of plist. Suppose i have a item "id = 2254" in my plist can i store in keychain with key as "id" and value as "2254". Thanks in advance